# Rotatinga cube in imageview in y axis in android

Tags: java, android

When I rotate a cube in image view , its rotating in circular direction in x-axis only. How can I change the direction of rotating path in y-axis
I given the code like this

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<set xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
  <rotate android:duration="5000"
          android:repeatCount="infinite"
          android:zAdjustment="normal"
          android:fillEnabled="true"
          android:startOffset="500"
          android:fromDegrees="0" 
          android:pivotX="50%"
          android:pivotY="50%"
          android:toDegrees="360">
  </rotate>
</set>
```

Java

```
 mainicon = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.message_list_actionbar_main_icon);
 Animation sampleFadeAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.rotate);
        sampleFadeAnimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        sampleFadeAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.START_ON_FIRST_FRAME);
        sampleFadeAnimation.setDuration(20000);
  mainicon.startAnimation(sampleFadeAnimation );
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: I given the xml code like this     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" >

    <rotate
        android:duration="5000"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:zAdjustment="normal"
        android:fillEnabled="true"
        android:startOffset="500"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="360" >
    </rotate>
</set>

Comment: mainicon = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.message_list_actionbar_main_icon);

 Animation sampleFadeAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.rotate);

        sampleFadeAnimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        sampleFadeAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.START_ON_FIRST_FRAME);
        sampleFadeAnimation.setDuration(20000);
  mainicon.startAnimation(sampleFadeAnimation )

Comment: Please add your code in the question. not as a comment. :)

Comment: It's a 2D rotate, it only allows rotate on the one axis. You may achieve your effect with a scale on one axis.

Comment: @weston how to add the scale value to the axis

Comment: I mean replace rotate with scale, then scale in only one axis.